# .htaccess rewrite rule for same words

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two rules causing problems:

```
RewriteRule ^posts$ posts.php
RewriteRule ^posts/create$ postscreate.php
```

I know that I could use "post/create" but these are just two rules out of more that are having all the same problem.

I worked with this rules perfectly on localhost (XAMPP).

However, once I moved the files to my hoster and visited "sub.domain.com/posts/create" it redirects me to posts.php instead of postscreate.php.

Why does it work fine on localhost but not on my hoster? And how can I fix it?

My full .htaccess looks like this (with the two rules only):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Options -Indexes

RewriteRule ^posts$ posts.php
RewriteRule ^posts/create$ postscreate.php
```

The .htaccess on localhost is exactly the same except the https rules. I also tried the .htaccess without the https rules on my hoster but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it work fine on localhost but not on my hoster? And how can I fix it?

It is most likely due to option `MultiViews` being turned on on hoster but turned off on localhost.

To disable this use this line on top of .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.